# prove that $f(x)$ isn't continuous based on a given relationship

Tags: continuity

I have functions $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with:
$$h(x)=cos(x)\cdot f(x)=e^x\cdot g(x)$$
If $h$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $g$ isn't continuous at $x_0$, then prove that $f$ isn't continuous at $x_0$.
Any ideas on how to solve it, because I stack in this.

Comment: $g(x)=e^{-x}\cos(x)f(x)$. If $f$ were continuous at $x_0$, what would happen ?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ then $g(x)\cdot e^x=\cos (x)\cdot f(x)$. Since $e^x$ is non-zero so we can say $g(x)=\cos (x)\cdot f(x)/e^x$, which is continuous at $x_0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split in two case:

1) $cos(x_0)\neq 0$ use $f(x)=\frac{e^xg(x)}{cos(x)}$ and use the discontinuity of g

2) $cos(x_0)=0$ use $f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{cos(x)}$ locally and use the discontinuity of $\frac{1}{cos(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

Because $h$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $g(x)=h(x)e^{-x}$ is also continuous at $x_0$, so your claim is wrong.

Comment: Indeed. And on base of a wrong claim everything can be proved.